# Refactoring a path in JS cannot find module

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Hi working on a project at the moment and currently getting it to call the api, great! however I'm looking at refactoring my test files as there will be quite a few so initially this is how I've done it.

```
    var chakram = require('chakram');
expect = chakram.expect;
var baseFixture = require('../../test/fixtures/');


it("Should return the matching test file", function () {


    var response = chakram.get("http://testurl");
    return expect(response).to.have.json(baseFixture + 'testfile.json')

});
```

However with the code above I'm getting this error.
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../test/fixtures'

If I put the json file into the variable at declared at the top with a call to base fixture within the function the test will pass.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i only use require to get file not path .. for getting path there are other function

Comment: What could I use instead of to try and achieve what I need to?

Comment: You can try `path` module of nodejs ... to do your job ..